Error 404 appear in console browser when execute JS script
I have an issue with my Javascript script that loads data for my website.
My site is hosted on my local PC, as well as the API I use. The website is not intended to be deployed online as it is a study project.
Currently, the site is fully functional, but I have one detail to fix. I'm asked to ensure that no JavaScript errors appear in the browser console. However, among the data I need to load, there are images hosted online. I only retrieve the image URL via the API.
So I load the image via the URL provided by the API to integrate it directly into my website, and this is where I'm stuck. Among these images, some are no longer available via the provided URL, which causes a 404 error in the browser console. I already replace these images with a locally hosted image when this happens. However, the error still appears in the browser because I still make a request to the image URL to determine if it's valid or not and replace it accordingly.
Do you know of a way to fix this? I've tried to handle it using try/catch and other methods like onload and onerror, but nothing works. The error still appears in the browser console.
PS: I'm not allowed to use plugins or modules
Thank you in advance for your help
I tried using try/catch and onload/onerror in different ways. In reality, I think it's an oversight on the part of those who designed the API four years ago, because the unavailable images have not been so for the past 2 to 3 years (I checked on waybackmachines). So, those working on the project today are faced with an error that cannot be handled when we do everything locally, despite being asked not to have any errors in the browser console (it's the only error that appears, everything else is perfect)

What is the exact error you receive? Is it a JavaScript error or HTTP error, and does the browser or API generate it? Does the API have a way to check the HTTP status code that is returned from the request?

I feel like such an idiot.. I just realized from your comment that the error generated in the web console is an HTTP error, not a JavaScript error. In essence, it's not a JavaScript error; my script simply takes the URL and places it in the corresponding HTML tag. Then the error is generated by the browser because it can't display an image that no longer exists at that URL...
I'm sorry for wasting your time with this post, and thank you for your responses

No problem at all, at least you know what the issue is now. Good luck with your project!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Make sure you allowed cors for domain of your website in the API

Hello, thank you for your response.
I don't need to enable cors on my domain because I only use the site locally. Additionally, my requests to retrieve images from public URLs work fine. The problem arises when a request is made to an image URL that is no longer available, resulting in a 404 error in the client-side browser console (which is normal). However, I can't find any way to prevent it from appearing in the browser console, even when handling it directly in my script. I think it's simply not possible (or very complicated), but I would like to confirm

When you answer a question, please do not just guess but ensure that it actually fixes the problem described. CORS issues are always visible in the JavaScript console. You can rule them out as the reason.

i didnt had enough reputation so i answered instead of comment
